# Magento sort products in category by pageviews

Tags: mysql, sorting, magento-1.7, product

I would like to sort products in category by popularity(popularity means pageviews). To realize this I created an attribute(page_view) which I increment on product details page and use this attribute to sort products in category. Everything works ok in terms of functionality but from performance point of view it is not a solution as because of increment and save product cost too much. It took around 5 second to load product details page while without it is around 0.9s. I tried to place this increment atribute code very deep system but it kill performance anyway. Does anyone have such problems? And maybe have some suggestions how to realize such things. Thank you in advance. Any technical deep explanations how/why it happens is very welcome. I know that it is atribute and $product->save(); affect a lot of products but anyway can't explain why so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure your attribute is part of the catalog_product flat table so you don't need to join to the EAV-tables to do that sort operation.

Comment: Hi Tobias, Thank you for your answer. It is already in flat table as it is used for sorting products in category.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I am going to answer socond time to my own question after finding the answer by myself, hope this will help someone sometime. The problem is that $product->save() is evil. It is very slow operation as it update a big amount of tables and this why it took several seconds. Instead of this I used saveAttribure() function which seems to be faster as it do less job on background. So remamber that "save" function of product is evil.